# Oracle 12.1.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 - Error in invoking target ''links proc gen_pcscfg procob'' of makefile ''<oraclehome>/precomp/lib/ins_precomp.mk''

Tags: oracle, ubuntu

I am trying to install Oracle database 12.1.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. I follow the instructions contained in http://www.techienote.com/install-oracle-12c-on-ubuntu/. At 59% of installation process, I am facing the below error.

Error in invoking target 'links proc gen_pcscfg procob' of makefile '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/precomp/lib/ins_precomp.mk'.

I have tried applying the below fix but the still exists. Can anyone suggest a solution for it.

rm -rf $ORACLE_HOME/lib/stubs/* cp $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk.orig

**Line 176**

FROM:
LINKTTLIBS=$(LLIBCLNTSH) $(ORACLETTLIBS) $(LINKLDLIBS)

TO :
LINKTTLIBS=$(LLIBCLNTSH) $(ORACLETTLIBS) $(LINKLDLIBS) -lons

**Line 279-280**

FROM:
LINK=$(FORT_CMD) $(PURECMDS) $(ORALD) $(LDFLAGS) $(COMPSOBJS) LINK32=$(FORT_CMD) $(PURECMDS) $(ORALD) $(LDFLAGS32) $(COMPSOBJS)

TO :
LINK=$(FORT_CMD) $(PURECMDS) $(ORALD) $(LDFLAGS) $(COMPSOBJS) -Wl,--no-as-needed LINK32=$(FORT_CMD) $(PURECMDS) $(ORALD) $(LDFLAGS32) $(COMPSOBJS) -Wl,--no-as-needed

**Line 3041-3042**

FROM:
TG4PWD_LINKLINE= $(LINK) $(OPT) $(TG4PWDMAI) \ $(LLIBTHREAD) $(LLIBCLNTSH) $(LINKLDLIBS)

TO :
TG4PWD_LINKLINE= $(LINK) $(OPT) $(TG4PWDMAI) \ $(LLIBTHREAD) $(LLIBCLNTSH) $(LINKLDLIBS) -lnnz12

Click the "Retry" button.

Answer (score 1):

You must change GCC option and remove pie. The default file path is :

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/orald
```

Change `exec ${CC} "$@"` to `exec ${CC} -no-pie "$@"`